# Google maps: Discrepancy between distance calculated for original path and distance calculated for ElevationResult path

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a path consisting of several LatLngs.
I calculate its length using the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < polyPath.length-1; i++) {  
      totalDistance2 = totalDistance2 +   
         google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(polyPath[i],polyPath[i+1]);
}
```

Now i send a request to ElevationService for this path and compute the distance of the path provided by the result.

```
for (i = 0; i < elevations.length-1; i++) {
      totalDistance = totalDistance + 
         google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(elevations[i].location,elevations[i+1].location);
}
```

For any path that i use there is always a discrepancy between the two distances reported, with the original path distance being always greater (by about 1%).

I have used 512 as the sample number for the elevation request. Lowering this increases the difference in distances.

edit: the path contains around 200-300 vertices

edit2: jsfiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wz3pup5o/ and the corresponding console output:
initial path length: 255
distance iterating over path latlngs: 8334.314359218815
distance using computelength(path): 8334.314359218815
distance iterating over elevation results: 8199.077136099133

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  How long is the initial path? If it is greater than 512, why would you expect the distance to be the same?

Comment: initial path is 200-300 vertices long

Comment: @geocodezip added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elevation points are equally spaced along the path.  The path created by connecting those points takes some shortcuts.  Examine the blue polyline in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wz3pup5o/1/) or the code snippet below.  Particularly around the sharp turns around point 213/214 and 218/219

**code snippet:**

```js
var path;
var map;
$(window).load(function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 20.0094671,
      lng: 73.3826942
    },
    zoom: 12,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  var polyString = "iibyBody~L|MiOs@eAiAw@YYO]Mk@Ca@IkAHu@r@_C`@s@^c@dA_Ax@sAdB{Az@u@Xs@\Wf@I`BYVIRUvA_CX_@JWBg@Ga@Qe@i@]Wa@@{AFaAIe@KQKKGOCk@Cc@IWQs@@aAB{AH{ANmBPs@Zw@`@}@Di@Cw@Ae@HaAHuBF_@\aALa@b@g@JSBOAIQQ}@u@KUCg@?aANgAp@oBbAmB\gAPm@Dm@FgDK{@Pm@Vu@d@eCFy@T{APQn@[x@i@JYGa@kA}Cy@_Cu@aCIy@@QFMx@y@zAqB\{A`@o@d@g@f@w@HMYJgB`@gA\_CbAo@n@YHQ?i@SOKIMCY@kANs@`@eBb@uAf@{@FQEMKEoADy@BQVOnAIVSJS@a@Gy@OSMi@mAg@e@gB_Aq@i@s@s@}AcBoBmA}Ag@k@YQYK[UYu@Yg@E_@?UEa@Om@K_Ce@oA[{@[oDaBoDuAsAa@Y?MFGNWP[Iu@a@e@c@i@Mi@AYBSRMRE`@KXsA`AU@SGY]SKMHAX@LHR`@~@VLj@PR?TKNEF?DFDPER_@j@ERB`@JhA?l@G`@Kb@ORm@^]FYA]Ok@Qc@MgBOgBM]Ig@[q@_BKw@Ay@EU[Mm@_@U[AYZmAFe@CKIAODWd@Sp@MRMAIMB]HMD_@?{@CIGCQ@[V_A~@MDO?OKe@iAWq@UUk@OOMC]A}Aj@_CNWRQj@UfA?^?HMLs@\gBz@mCv@iCvA_CnA{BcBRgGj@w@Ro@FsBPo@Lk@PPn@";

  path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(polyString);

  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: 'purple',
    map: map,
    strokeWeight: 4
  });

  var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

  elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
    path: path,
    samples: 512
  }, calcdistance);

});

function calcdistance(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

    var totalDistance2 = 0;
    console.log('initial path length:' + path.length);
    for (i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
      totalDistance2 = totalDistance2 + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(path[i], path[i + 1]);
    }
    console.log('distance iterating over path latlngs:' + totalDistance2);
    console.log('distance using computelength(path):' + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path));

    var totalDistance = 0;
    var epath = [];
    var old_loc = results[0].location;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var new_loc;
    console.log("results.length=" + results.length);
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      new_loc = results[i].location;
      epath.push(new_loc);
      bounds.extend(new_loc);
      var m = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: "" + i,
        position: new_loc,
        icon: {
          url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
          size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
        }
      });
      totalDistance = totalDistance + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(old_loc, new_loc);
      old_loc = new_loc;
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: epath,
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      map: map,
      strokeWeight: 1
    });
    console.log('distance iterating over elevation results:' + totalDistance);
    console.log('distance using computelength(epath):' + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(epath));
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I was confused by the fact that the number of vertices of the original path was less than 512. But as you correctly pointed out elevation service places them equally spaced out and not "smartly". Thanks for clearing things up!